# Create a watch only wallet descriptor with bitcoin core

Tags: wallet, watch-only

Trying to create a watch only wallet descriptor in bitcoin core client.

```
bitcoin-cli -named createwallet wallet_name=mywallet descriptors=true
```

This just returns an error: method not found. Furthermore running the command with -testnet returns that the server is not enabled, make sure using correct rpcport.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using v0.20.99

Comment: If it helps, your command works on v22.0.0